# pass object to setState fails

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I created my own web-app of posts where you able to add,delete and update posts. Right now when I try to add a post and pass the inputs value throw a function and then execute 'setState' I get an error, something is wrong in the way I do it. could you help out?

I could just remove the root object from the state ('post') and just use the title,body as for themselfs. But I want to structure it this way: Post:{title,body}

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
export class addPost extends Component {
  state = {
    post: {
      title: '',
      body: ''
    }
  };
  handleChange = e => {
    this.setState({ post[e.currentTarget.id]: e.currentTarget.value });
    console.log(this.state);
  };
  handleSubmit = () => {};
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          Enter title:
          <input
            type="text"
            value={this.state.title}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
            id="title"
          />
          Enter body:
          <input
            type="text"
            value={this.state.body}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
            id="body"
          />
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default addPost;
```

I expect to pass this object post:{title:'sometext',body:'sometext'}

Comment: made a sandbox for you to replicate the solution that I wrote. This should give you some context on how to update your state properly. See console.logs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Made a sandbox for you: https://codesandbox.io/s/p2w7765j0

Most conventions are to use the name property for your inputs and map them using `event.target.name`

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class AddPost extends Component {
  state = {
    post: {
      title: "",
      body: ""
    }
  };

  handleChange = event => {
    this.setState(
      {
        post: {
          ...this.state.post,
          [event.target.name]: event.target.value
        }
      },
      () => console.log(this.state)
    );
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          Enter title:
          <input
            type="text"
            value={this.state.post.title}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
            name="title"
          />
          Enter body:
          <input
            type="text"
            value={this.state.post.body}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
            name="body"
          />
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default AddPost;
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to fix on two places

1. Where you are setting state
2. Where you are accessing state in input

```js
handleChange = e => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      post: { ...prevState.post, [e.target.id]: e.target.value }
    }));
  };
  
  
  <input value={this.state.post.title />
  <input value={this.state.post.body} />
```

Comment: At least put some effort to fix the syntax errors. Compare starting and closing brackets

Comment: @hindi1991 I have fixed the syntax error. Have a look